# What was the apocalypse that preceeded Sora no Woto?

Tags: sora-no-woto

The series Sora no Woto was based in a post-apocalyptic world that significantly reduced the technological capability of mankind. (Takemikazuchi spider tanks -> mundane tanks)

Then entire show focuses on events after the apocalypse, with only a glimpse of flash-backs to earlier events during the apocalypse. But for the most part, the apocalypse itself is largely shrouded.

[image]

Are there any details about:

1. What the apocalypse was?
2. How did it happen?
3. What did the pre-apocalyptic world look like?

Comment: Some speculation on this is at http://soranowoto.wikia.com/wiki/Speculation

Answer (score 2):

I'm still learning english, but this is what I understood.

1. The apocalypse is related to the legend that Yumina describes in chapter 12. It could have been the great war against one angel (it appears on chapter 7 partially, you could see black wings in the windows- this happens when Felicia remember her past).
2. The enemy was extremely strong, even a takemikazuchi was not enough to fight against the "angel". I am not sure if it´s an alien or maybe advanced technology from that time. The "angel" uses a laser to destroy a city.
3. The world look likes today, some buildings without great technology, the only remarkable thing was takemikazuchi. Chapter 7 has more details.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood after watching this series:

The world has been mostly destroyed by a war. We don't really know if it is a war between humans or between humans and aliens.

The world of sora no woto seems to be destroyed between 2000-2010, because of several allusions to this era during the anime.

We don't know much because I suspect this series was supposed to be part of a bigger multiverse.

One hypothesis is that this series has a tie-in with occult gakuin as they were two series from the same anime no chikara TV block. Basically, the story of occult gakuin is about someone from the future that comes back in the past to avoid the apocalypse that happened in his time period.